# Can JavaScript insert a new element without showing that element in the page source?

Tags: javascript, html

Some background: I'm making a puzzle, so I'm ok with doing some strange things (like disabling right-click) just to force players to use other methods to solve.

In one part I have an invisible element, and it gets placed randomly onscreen. It works exactly how I want it to, however all it would take is for a player to open dev tools and hover the element in the source to have it highlighted and know exactly where the element is on the page.

So I'm curious if there's a way to insert the button to the page, but keep it out of sight in dev tools?

My current function for inserting the element, in case it's relevant. I imagine if it's possible, I will need to adjust this somehow.

```js
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}
```

I don't want to hide all source code, as it's actually a part of the puzzle to look in there. If there's no way to hide the button like I'm asking, I will just have to find another way. Appreciate any insight!

Comment: Does it have to be a real button? Perhaps you can register an onclick handler on the whole page body or some container div, then if you know the offset that the clickable area is supposed to be at, you can just do some math in your click handler to know if they've clicked in the correct region or not. Of course, even this can be reversed engineer, it's just a bit harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but keep it out of sight in dev tools?

No, you cannot. Nothing in the DOM can be hidden from the DOM Explorer, otherwise it wouldn't be very useful.

(I'll admit that there *is* the Shadow DOM, which is hidden/collapsed by default in the DOM Explorer's node tree, but the "Show selected element" tool will always work regardless of Shadow DOM settings).

> I will just have to find another way

- The only "other way" is to require your users to run Chrome with a system policy setting to disable Dev Tools - which is only possible if:

  - Your users are running Windows machines in an Active Directory Domain that you control and [you set the necessary Group Policy setting](https://admx.help/?Category=Chrome&Policy=Google.Policies.Chrome::DeveloperToolsDisabled).
  - Your users are running Windows machines using an MDM Profile that you control (which sets the same Policy setting).
  - Your users are running Chromebooks enrolled into the same G Suite account [and you disabled Dev Tools in your device policy options](https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023904853-How-to-disable-developer-tools-for-Chromebooks-).
- Another alternative is to require your users to access your application/quiz/test/etc via a Remote Desktop / VNC / etc session that runs Chrome remotely on a machine that *does* set the Group Policy.

  - There are `<canvas>`-based Remote Desktop clients now.
- Otherwise, provided it's your HTML, JS and CSS that you've published to the public web then, *no*, you absolutely cannot stop users from using their machines to view and manipulate HTML, JS, and CSS the way *they* want to. That's just how the *free and open* world wide web works.

  - After all, how else would ad-blockers work?

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept as the answer when SO allows me to.

Comment: Just noticed your edit. I had considered a VNC thing, but it's just a little too complicated for the audience. Ease of access is more important than hiding the button. I decided to repurpose the button, and actually make finding the button through the source code by highlighting the answer to that particular part of the problem.

Thanks for the extra thought on it!

Answer (score 0):

How about filling the page with thousands of dummy nodes whose position in the DOM keeps changing every second?

Comment: Ah yes, _The Facebook Maneuver_: https://css-tricks.com/how-facebook-avoids-ad-blockers/ - however I think we can all agree today that advising someone to imitate Facebook is probably the worst advice to give.

Comment: @dai OP said it was for a puzzle. It would be good for their puzzle solvers to learn some of the tricks people use on the Internet to sharpen their skills.